# Strong and Practical Hand Ciphers

Tags: classical-cipher, pen-and-paper

I know monoalphabetic ciphers are weak, but my message recipient doesn't like taking the time for the decryption process. I've tried Vigenere, Gronsfeld, Beaufort and Digraphic Ciphers, but he doesn't decrypt them. What is a good choice for speed and enough security against novice cryptanalysts? One-Time-Pad is highly impractical, and Solitaire takes too much time, what is the best bet? Your suggested answer gives me systems that are impractical and slow. I don't need high security, merely simple yet strong ciphers not mentioned above.

Comment: @Maarten The answers given in the suggested duplicate aren't practical for my use.

Comment: I think an issues with answers might be that you've said _"merely simple yet strong ciphers"_ whilst targetting _"novice cryptanalysts"_ but tried (unsuccessfully) to use monoalphabetic ciphers.  Might 'he' be the real problem? Otherwise you'll be left with [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).